# Can I see what apps I own that have been pulled from the market by developers?

Tags: google-play-store, paid-apps

Last year I purchased the app grüvtron by Sound Trends LLC. Presumably they later removed the app from the google play store / market. Their website used to have a "buy android version" but now only mentions ios.

The app can no longer be found by searching the market (neither on the device, nor on the web). I can no longer see it under "all apps" / "my apps" (again, neither on the device, nor on the web). The only reason I knew this app was "missing" was because I remembered owning it.

Using google I could find an old market link in a forum to 
  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.soundtrends.gruvtron
This link normally gives "We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server".

However, if I happen to be logged in to my google account that owns the app, I get a market page for the app (!) from which I can chose to install it! Doing so, it indeed gets sent to my device and 'everything works' (though, the app graphics are broken -- but I don't think that is relevant here.)

This is worrying. Obviously I have no idea how many of the ~100s of apps I own that have silently disappeared from "my apps", and thus are left out when I browse that list for things to re-install. And even if I remembered a specific app, how would I find the corresponding market link so that I could re-install it?

So my primary question is:
**Is there a list anywhere on the web or on the android device that lists all apps I own -- *including the ones pulled from the market*?** and **preferably with market links?**

I have the google market receipts, but those are a pain to go through (it is not really a "list") Worse, in there I only see a company name and textual app name, i.e., no market link. If there had been any reference to the app id (e.g., here, 'com.soundtrends.gruvtron') I could at least have re-constructed the market url.

---

Edit: a few clarifications follows:

1. A satisfactory answer must describe a way to get a list of apps which includes those I have purchased, **but which after the date of purchase have been pulled from the market by developers.** The list should include either market URLs or package-names.
2. The single one of my purchased apps where I know this has happened (grüvtron) **does not appear under my "my apps" list** (Menu > My Apps in market app), and I assume this is intentional design for apps that have been pulled (though I find it an odd design choice).
3. I am currently on ICS, with market 3.7.13. The device is the ASUS transformer TF101 tablet.

Comment: Yeah I know exactly why you're asking. I had a malware app get removed only today and there may be more, but there's no easy way to track this. Good job, dude.

Comment: Related: [How to get notified about removed apps from play store?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/134903)

Answer (score 2):

The application listed above, "AppBak," gets its data from the android package manager class; if you've got root access, you can see the source (/data/dev/packages.list) which is a simple text file that lists only currently installed apks, but there's also an XML file in the same subdirectory, of the same name, which is considerably larger:  packages.xml, and where it seems even uninstalled packages tend to remain. I found proof of my former bloatware freezer application in there once, and while it didn't do me a world of good, at least I had a resource I could check to see what went disappearing in the night.

The question I can't answer is if the Market can now wipe that data from packages.xml. But I'd point out that [the PackageManager documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) has a Get_Uninstalled_Packages constant on that page, so I'd guess not.

Comment: `packages.list` and `packages.xml` are under `/data/system/`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the f-droid's repository, this app, '[AppBak](http://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.moparisthebest.appbak&fdpage=1)' will generate the list of apps installed on your handset into a simple flat text file on your SD-Card.

The crucial thing to remember, is the '**package-name**' is the most important part of it, and is at the developer's choosing and discretion.

For example, an app called '*FooBar*', that appears in the application drawer, the package name would be '*com.foo.bar.app*', from there it is quite easy to reconstruct a market link from that as in:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.foo.bar.app
```

Comment: Seems to be a useful tool, thanks! But this will only give you the package-name of apps *installed* on the device, right? The main issue here is to find package-names of apps I previously purchased, but do not currently have installed (and cannot install, since they are invisible.)

Comment: It lists the apps *installed* on the device - yes

Comment: It should show up on the play store app on your handset, tap Menu > My Apps, not on the web based on PC that is, unless I have misunderstood you? FWIW, my Play Store version is 3.7.13

Comment: Not for apps that have been pulled from the market, I think. I guess it could be a specific problem with the app I mention in the question, since I don't know another one I both own and that has been pulled. I'm also on 3.7.13. Can you confirm seeing any app in your "My apps" that **has been pulled from market?**

Comment: Based on above mentioned information, you could built yourself a script which checks the URLs (without you being logged in). For "disappeared" apps, an "Error 404" (page not found) should be returned.

Comment: Izzy, your suggestion assumes I already have a list of all apps I own (i.e., both those still on the market and those pulled). But the only list I can produce from google / android is a list over apps that *excludes* those that have been pulled.