# How to check which installed apps have been taken off the google play store?

Tags: google-play-store, restore, google-backup

Each time I restore my apps using my Google account I find out that some apps were just left out; the apps were no longer available on the Google Play Store.

How can I confirm that all apps installed via the Google play store are still available on the Google Play Store, so that when I restore my backup via my Google account I don't have apps missing.

I would do this by using an Apk Exporter to store the apps which are no longer available on the Google Play Store.

Comment: The easiest way to check if an app is still in Play Store kein my opinion the Google Play web site. The app package name is in the URL and if the app is still in store the web page exists, if not an error page is displayed. Using the device package list gained by `pm list packages` and a small script it would be possible to filter out apps that are missing in Play Store. May be there is already an app that uses this way to check the installed apps but I don't know such an app.

Comment: See [How to get notified about removed apps from Google Play Store?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/134903/96277). Has my own answer there written long time ago.

Comment: While Firelord's linked question has a title that is more specific ("notify" vs "check"), I believe his automation approach should work well in general, and I may consider this a duplicate of that question. Consider trying his answer and let us know. Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewT. I was more assuming there would be an app that could be installed rather than scripts.